# Find full path from list of tree subpaths

Tags: sql, postgresql, ltree

Is there a simple way to find the full path and update it for all topic with such data structure.

```
                 TOPIC_0000070 
                     | 
                 TOPIC_0000054
             /       |          \
    TOPIC_0000000 TOPIC_0000001 TOPIC_0000002
```

- Initial data:

`CREATE TABLE topics (id varchar, path ltree);`

```
INSERT INTO "topics"(id, path) VALUES ('TOPIC_0000000', 'TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000000');
INSERT INTO "topics"(id, path) VALUES ('TOPIC_0000001', 'TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000001');
INSERT INTO "topics"(id, path) VALUES ('TOPIC_0000002', 'TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000002');
INSERT INTO "topics"(id, path) VALUES ('TOPIC_0000054', 'TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054');
INSERT INTO "topics"(id, path) VALUES ('TOPIC_0000070', 'TOPIC_0000070');
```

```
id           | path                      |
-------------+---------------------------+
TOPIC_0000000|TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000000|
TOPIC_0000001|TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000001|
TOPIC_0000002|TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000002|
...          |...                        |
TOPIC_0000054|TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054|
TOPIC_0000070|TOPIC_0000070              |
```

- The expected result:

```
id           | path                                    |
-------------+-----------------------------------------+
TOPIC_0000000|TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000000|
TOPIC_0000001|TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000001|
TOPIC_0000002|TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000002|
...          |...                                      |
TOPIC_0000054|TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054              |
TOPIC_0000070|TOPIC_0000070                            |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can arrive to that following a series of steps:

I recreated your table as

```
CREATE TABLE topics (id varchar, path varchar);
```

and inserted the same rows as per your example

### 1. Recursive query

```
WITH RECURSIVE path_finder AS
  (SELECT t.id,
          t.path PATH
   FROM topics t
   UNION SELECT pf.id,
                p.path || coalesce('.' || pf.id, p.id)
   FROM topics p
   INNER JOIN path_finder pf ON substring(pf.path, 0, position('.' in pf.path)) = p.id
   WHERE p.id <> p.path 
select * from path_finder order by 1,2
```

The join here checks that the prefix of a `path` string equals the `id` of an anchestor

```
substring(pf.path,0,position('.' in pf.path)) = p.id
```

The output of the above will correctly show al the combinations

```
defaultdb-> select * from path_finder order by 1,2;
      id       |                   path                    
---------------+-------------------------------------------
 TOPIC_0000000 | TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000000
 TOPIC_0000000 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000000
 TOPIC_0000001 | TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000001
 TOPIC_0000001 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000001
 TOPIC_0000002 | TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000002
 TOPIC_0000002 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000002
 TOPIC_0000054 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054
 TOPIC_0000070 | TOPIC_0000070
(8 rows)
```

### 2. Ranking

Now it's time to rank the output of step 1, we'll rank based on the number of dots (`.`) in the string, we can do that with

```
SELECT *,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                       ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(PATH) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(PATH, '.', '')) DESC) rnk
   FROM path_finder
   WHERE PATH <> ''
   ORDER BY 1,
            2
```

result

```
      id       |                   path                    | rnk 
---------------+-------------------------------------------+-----
 TOPIC_0000000 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000000 |   1
 TOPIC_0000000 | TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000000               |   2
 TOPIC_0000001 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000001 |   1
 TOPIC_0000001 | TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000001               |   2
 TOPIC_0000002 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000002 |   1
 TOPIC_0000002 | TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000002               |   2
 TOPIC_0000054 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054               |   1
 TOPIC_0000070 | TOPIC_0000070                             |   1
(8 rows)
```

### 3. Final select filtering only the rows with ranking = 1

Full code

```
WITH RECURSIVE path_finder AS
  (SELECT t.id,
          t.path PATH
   FROM topics t
   UNION SELECT pf.id,
                p.path || coalesce('.' || pf.id, p.id)
   FROM topics p
   INNER JOIN path_finder pf ON substring(pf.path, 0, position('.' in pf.path)) = p.id
   WHERE p.id <> p.path ),
               ranking_rows AS
  (SELECT *,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                       ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(PATH) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(PATH, '.', '')) DESC) rnk
   FROM path_finder
   WHERE PATH <> ''
   ORDER BY 1,
            2)
SELECT *
FROM ranking_rows
WHERE rnk=1;
```

result

```
      id       |                   path                    | rnk 
---------------+-------------------------------------------+-----
 TOPIC_0000000 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000000 |   1
 TOPIC_0000001 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000001 |   1
 TOPIC_0000002 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000002 |   1
 TOPIC_0000054 | TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054               |   1
 TOPIC_0000070 | TOPIC_0000070                             |   1
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by splitting your rows into `complete` and `incomplete` based on whether the row's path begins at a root `id`.

```
with top_paths as (   -- Find the roots
  select path as top
    from topics 
   where nlevel(path) = 1
), complete as (      -- Find the complete paths
  select t.*
    from topics t
         join top_paths tp
           on tp.top = subpath(t.path, 0, 1)
), incomplete as (    -- Get the incomplete paths
  select *
    from topics t
   where id not in (select id from complete)
)
```

I would then join the `incomplete` records back to the `complete` records and apply some `ltree` surgery to rewrite the `incomplete` paths.

```
select *
  from complete
union all
select i.id, c.path||subpath(i.path, 1, 999) as path
  from incomplete i
       join complete c  -- make this a left join if you are worried about breaking the tree
         on c.id::ltree = subpath(i.path,  0, 1)
 order by path;

┌───────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────┐
│      id       │                   path                    │
├───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ TOPIC_0000070 │ TOPIC_0000070                             │
│ TOPIC_0000054 │ TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054               │
│ TOPIC_0000000 │ TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000000 │
│ TOPIC_0000001 │ TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000001 │
│ TOPIC_0000002 │ TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000002 │
└───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

Feeding this into an `update` statement, you will not need the `complete` rows.

```
with top_paths as (
  select path as top
    from topics 
   where nlevel(path) = 1
), complete as (
  select t.*
    from topics t
         join top_paths tp
           on tp.top = subpath(t.path, 0, 1)
), incomplete as (
  select *
    from topics t
   where id not in (select id from complete)
), fixes as (
  select i.id, c.path||subpath(i.path, 1, 999) as path
    from incomplete i
         join complete c
           on c.id::ltree = subpath(i.path,  0, 1)
)
update topics
   set path = fixes.path
  from fixes
 where fixes.id = topics.id;
```

Results:

```
select * from topics order by path;

┌───────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────┐
│      id       │                   path                    │
├───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ TOPIC_0000070 │ TOPIC_0000070                             │
│ TOPIC_0000054 │ TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054               │
│ TOPIC_0000000 │ TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000000 │
│ TOPIC_0000001 │ TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000001 │
│ TOPIC_0000002 │ TOPIC_0000070.TOPIC_0000054.TOPIC_0000002 │
└───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┘
(5 rows)
```